# Why does "for item in list" loop only go half way?

Tags: python

I'm trying to modify a loop function that contains over a hundred lines of code.

If I have a loop in python that goes through a list, why does a `for item in list:` loop only finish half way through? Shouldn't it keep looping until all items are popped?

For example if I have this list:

```
 l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]


    for item in l1:
        l1.pop(0)
        print l1
```

No matter how many items the list contains, it will only finish when 50% of the list has been popped:

OUTPUT FOR CODE ABOVE:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 6]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can I still pop each item in the list without changing the `for item in l1:` loop?

Comment: You're modifying a list while iterating over it. Possible duplicate of a _lot of questions in SO_ :)

Comment: Why are you modifying a list as you're looping over it?

Comment: print out `item` as well and you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a copy of the list and pop from the original one:

```
In [1]: l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [2]: for item in l1[:]:
   ...:     l1.pop(0)
   ...:     print l1
   ...:     
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6]
[6]
[]
```

However, this is certainly not elegant.